# Why cant I remove element from array in Reactjs with redux

Tags: arrays, reactjs, redux

I am dynamically adding <div> elements to a component by adding them to an array. This is not a problem and works well. The issue I'm trying to solve here is removing the <div> on double click by passing the id of the <div> that was doubled clicked with props when the reducer is dispatched.

**The main issue is the array filter function only works when I code hard the div id both on the div and in the filter function when I want to pass the id of e.target.id on dispatch of delDiv reducer.**

**Note:** I can remove the div successfully by changing the addDivReducer like this:

```
case "ADD_DIV":
  return state.concat(
        <DivComponent 
          key={Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1} 
          id={11} ***************************************************** Changed
         />
  );

case "DELETE_DIV":
  state = state.filter((elements) => {
    return elements.props.id !== 11; *********************************** Changed
  });
  return state;
```

**But the desired effect is to pass id as props on dispatch as seen in my code below**

The reducer that adds a removes elements look like this:

```
import DivComponent from "../../components/AddDivComponent";

const addDivReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {

    case "ADD_DIV":
      return state.concat(
        <DivComponent 
          key={Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1} 
          id={Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1} 
         />
      );

    case "DELETE_DIV":
      state = state.filter((elements) => {
        return elements.props.id !== action.payload;
      });
      return state;

    default:
      return (state = []);
  }
};

export default addClipartReducer;
```

The actions index.js look like:

```
export const addDiv = (props) => {
  return {
    type: "ADD_DIV",
    payload: props,
  };
};

export const deleteDiv = (props) => {
  return {
    type: "DELETE_DIV",
    payload: props,
  };
};
```

The delete reducer is being dispatched when the div is double clicked on like this in AddDivComponent.js:

```
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { deleteDiv } from "../../store/actions";

const AddDivComponent = (props) => {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const removeClipart = (e) => {
    dispatch(deleteDiv(e.target.id));
  };

    return(
      <div
        id={props.id}
        className="my-div"
        onDoubleClick={removeDiv}
      />
     
    );
};

export default DivComponent;
```

Finally the array of <div> elements is being shown here in Canvas.js:

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const Canvas = () => {

  const divList = useSelector((state) => state.addDIV);
  
  return(
    <div className="canvas">
      {divList}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Canvas;
```

Comment: don't store components at state, that's no good. store its properties in an object like `{ key, id }` and consume them when rendering at your components

Comment: @buzatto Why not? Just so I know. Also I'm mainly concerned with why the array.filter wont work unless I hard code an id both in the div and in the filter function,

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if its a type error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are mutating state at your `DELETE_DIV` reducer. If you need to handle state, create a copy a first:

```
  // mutating state here to a new value, can lead to problems
  state = state.filter((elements) => {
    return elements.props.id !== action.payload;
  });
```

I would suggest to return filter directly, given filter already returns the desired next state, while not mutating the original:

```
case "DELETE_DIV":
  return state.filter((elements) => {
    return elements.props.id !== action.payload;
  });
```